# How to affect a custom google map style in Ionic v6 capacitor?

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I can't find the solution for apply a custom style on my google map app build with ionic !

I generate a Id map and i create a custom map in Google Cloud Platform.

But how i can use it ?

I use Ionic 6.19.1 and Angular.

**Html:**

```
<capacitor-google-maps #map></capacitor-google-maps>
```

---

**Angular:**

```
this.Map = await GoogleMap.create({
  id: 'Map',
  element: this.mapRef.nativeElement,
  apiKey: environment.apiKey,
  
  config: {
    center: {
      lat: 40,
      lng: 5,
    },
     zoom: 10,      
  },
});
```

i follow this official tutorial: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/google-maps#usage

Thank in advance

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mRSuR6d_L0 check this link

Answer (score 0):

On you capacitor map config object You could add styles property:

```
  styles = [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#523735"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f1e6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9b2a6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dcd2be"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ae9e90"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#93817c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a5b076"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#447530"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f1e6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#fdfcf8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f8c967"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e9bc62"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e98d58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#db8555"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#806b63"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#8f7d77"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#b9d3c2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#92998d"
      }
    ]
  }
];

  async createMap() {
    this.newMap = await GoogleMap.create({
      id: 'my-cool-map',
      element: this.mapRef.nativeElement,
      apiKey: environment.apiKey,
      config: {
styles : this.styles,
        center: {
          lat: 33.6,
          lng: -117.9,
        },
        zoom: 8,
      },
    });
  }
```

You could generate custom styles from google dashboard:
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
Or You could get different styles templates from this website:
https://snazzymaps.com/
just expand code then save its value on styles array.

Comment: It does not work :(

Comment: If You mean css style not map theme use capacitor-google-maps#map{} to apply your styel

Comment: I cant add style in config:{} because "style" does not exist in GoogleMapConfig interface...
Thank for your answer.

Comment: styles not style

Comment: After a lot of search I find out that capacitor  google map official version doesn't support having styles as attribute yet.Check from this.Map ref to apply it using vanilla javascript  .

Comment: I have created an issue for this plugin on github to add styles property to config object.